# jQuery post button name

Tags: jquery, post

I have simple form:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="IDD">    
<input type="email" name="user_email" />
<input type="button" name="login" value="login" onclick="pp()" />    
</form>

<script>

    function pp()
    {
        $("#IDD").submit();
    }

</script>
```

The value of "user_email" is in the post var, but the name of the submit button is not. I'm doing it wiht jquery cause I have some extra code that check if checkboxes are checked.

Comment: The `$("#IDD").submit();` is redundant since you seem to be doing nothing from stopping your submit button from performing it's normal action. If you do have more code that might be affecting the form, then post it please.

Comment: I'm not sur to understand what you want to do but I'm sure that the name of submit button is never sent !  to do that you can add `<input type="hidden" value="what you want" />` or pass an argument to your function onClick="pp(this.name);"

Comment: But when I post it it doesn't recognize if(isset($_POST["login"]))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the following

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="IDD">    
<input type="email" name="user_email" />
<input type="submit" name="login" id="loginButton" value="login"/>    
</form>
```

The problem is, form doesn't send values of input type button. You should set it's type to submit if you want to receive its value on server.

Note: if there are more than one submit buttons in your form, you'll only get the value of the button that was clicked.

**Update:**
You can use jQuery like below

```
$("#loginButton").click(function (evt) {
    if (!conditonMeets) { // check what ever condition you have here
        return false; // this will stop form from submitting
    }
});
```

Note: I have assigned an Id to Login button

Comment: But before form is submitted I need to check if some of checkboxes inside this form (which I did not include) are checked or not. And if they are then it could be submitted

Comment: I don't understand why this code has to be after my form to work?

Comment: wrap this code in $(document).ready(function(){//place code here});. This way you can put it anywhere on the page